# Date validation VB6

Tags: validation, date, vb6

I have a masked textbox where users keep slipping in invalid dates - and when they get saved to SQL SERVER, there's an error. This is my validation on _lostFocus

```
If txtDate = "" Then
    Exit Function
ElseIf Not IsDate(txtDate) Then
    Exit Function
End If
```

I can put in a date such as 19/8/2000 and it passes. How can I validate it so that it's a valid date?

Found the issue - so this function never converts it to mm/dd/yyyy format - it gets automatically converted to dd/mm/yyyy. How would I convert it?

when i format it to txtDate = Format(txtDate , "mm/dd/yyyy") before I run it trhough the little if statement - the date simply gets converted to 8/19/2000 in that case

Inside the textbox the date basically changes to 8/19/2000 - why is it doing that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why can't you use If `Date.TryParse(txtDate, Date)` Then...? If it succeeds then it's a valid date otherwise it's not. Also 19/8/2000 is a valid date, that's why it passes. If you want to show it in another form or another use `ToString` with the format you want... Inside the textbox the date basically changes to 8/19/2000 simply because you are formatting it... Also `IsDate(txtDate)` this wont work if it's a TextBox, use `IsDate(txtDate.Text)`